# How to update Node version in Codespace

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, codespaces, github-codespaces

I am trying to use Node version 16 in a codespace.

First I ran `nvm install-latest-nvm`.

Then I ran `nvm use 16` which returned `Now using node v16.18.1 (npm v9.1.1)`

However, `node -v` then returns `v14.20.1`.

And I'm still getting the same errors from dependencies which require Node v16.

How do I get the codespace to show that it is using v16, via `node -v`?

Comment: ^ However, that answer also hasn't been answered. I'll answer it there.